# Функция нахождения максимума

Tags: c++

Почему функция

```
int max1(int x,int y)
 {
    return x>y ? x : y;
 }
```

работает медленнее, чем

```
 int max2(int x,int y)
 {
    return x<y ? y : x;
 }
```

?

[Вот](http://zealcomputing.ru/besedy/019/#more-222) нашёл статью про это даже (в конце таблицы сравнения скоростей)

Вот моё сравнение:

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cstdlib>
 #include <algorithm>
 #include <vector>
 #include <utility>
 #include <ctime>
 int max1(int x,int y)
 {
    return x>y ? x : y;
 }
 int max2(int x,int y)
 {
    return x<y ? y : x;
 }
 int main()
 {
    std::srand(unsigned(std::time(0)));
    const unsigned long long size = 1000000000;
    std::vector<std::pair<int,int>> v(size);
    std::for_each(v.begin(),v.end(),[](std::pair<int,int>& x){x=std::make_pair(std::rand(),std::rand());});
    unsigned int start1 = clock();
    for (auto i : v) max1(i.first,i.second);
    unsigned int end1 = clock();
    std::cout << end1-start1 << std::endl;
    unsigned int start2 = clock();
    for (auto i : v) max2(i.first,i.second);
    unsigned int end2 = clock();
    std::cout << end2-start2 << std::endl;
 }
```

Comment: Как и на каких данных сравнивали, и насколько большие отличия?

Comment: приведите алгоритм сравения, функции с большой вероятностью будут преобразованы в одинаковый ассемблерный код.

Comment: @nikolay - Вы задали вопрос, в котором содержится предполагаемое поведение, не приведя абсолютно никаких данных, позволяющих это поведение воспроизвести.

Comment: обновил вопрос.

Comment: ну там всё и написано в поясениях, а вообще это зависит от конкретной версии компилятора архитектуры и так далее.

Comment: "медленнее" - это 1.42 vs 1.39?

Comment: Igor, нет, там 0.83 vs 1.39 для минимума.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Я как раз недавно рассматривал подобный вопрос в [этой статье](http://zealcomputing.ru/besedy/019/) (в самом конце).

У меня получилось так, что на архитектуре x86 всё зависит от порядка сравнения. Если x сравнивается с y, то компилятор даёт одну последовательность команд, а если наоборот, то другую последовательность **тех же самых** команд. Причина разницы в скорости, видимо, в особенностях микроархитектуры. Одна последовательность команд, видимо, лучше ложится на конвейер или ещё какие-то сторонние факторы влияют.

Это общая беда, наверное, всех процессоров Intel. Аналогично, я заметил, что команда `inc eax` будет работать медленнее, чем `lea eax, [eax+1]`. Подобных приколов, наверное, ещё много.

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не знал, что вы как раз у меня в статье эту мысль и рассмотрели. Нужно было сразу сказать...

Comment: одна и та же статья что в вопросе что в ответе) я понимаю что ответ был набран до того как статья в вопросе появилась, но видимо автор не понял что-то из статьи.

Comment: Вы знаете, я как автор статьи тоже не очень-то понял, почему так : )

Comment: на самом деле весь механизм замера кривоватый, гнать i от 0 до 0 это UB, всё сравенение компилятор может сжать до присваивания сразу или кусками. И проверьте, что поменяв a и b местами, результат не меняется на противоположный. И да опции бы компиляции увидеть, может поиграв с -O3 -O2 -OX разные будут результаты.

Comment: VC++ 2015 сгенерировал совершенно одинаковый код, с совершенно одинаковым временем выполнения...

Comment: @pavel, не UB. Там же `u32`, а для unsigned-типов переполнение определено.

Comment: Я измерял именно процессорное время работы программы с помощью специальной замерялки [runexe](http://code.google.com/p/runexe). Так что ошибка будет меньше, чем разница в скорости.

Comment: @Harry, это неправда (хотя, может дело в опциях?) Я именно этим компилятором всё и проверял.

Comment: У меня опция одна /Ox, компилятор VC++ 2015, Windows 7 - 64, но код генерировал 32-битный.

Comment: @Zealint Можно предположить, что у процессора есть специальная оптимизация для идущих подряд инструкций cmp и команды использующей флаги (cmovl) укладывание их в один такт (вполне разумное поведение, учитывая что пишущие на asm обычно подряд и пишут) то вставка между ними mov может не позволить выполнить такую оптимизацию.

Comment: @Zealint При /Ox выкинуло нафиг вызовы - померять ничего нельзя: 0 и все. Но тут код действительно немного разный - max2:  `mov eax, DWORD PTR _x$[esp-4]
 cmp eax, DWORD PTR _y$[esp-4]
 cmovl eax, DWORD PTR _y$[esp-4]`
-------- и max1:   `mov eax, DWORD PTR _y$[esp-4]
 cmp DWORD PTR _x$[esp-4], eax
 cmovg eax, DWORD PTR _x$[esp-4]`
(извините уж за неформатированность). При /Od - байт в байт одинаковый.

Comment: @Harry, я не понимаю, почему у Вас так, но у меня мой код с /Ox отлично компилируется и работает так, как мне нужно.

Comment: @Harry, так вы, наверное, код автора вопроса пытаетесь компилировать?

Comment: @Zealint Естественно - ведь его утверждение относится именно к этому коду :)

Comment: @Harry, ну, там понятно, что циклы будут удалены. В своём коде я обязательно внутри цикла делаю некое действие (например, накапливаю сумму, которую затем вывожу), чтобы он не удалился. Там в статье приведён фрагмент цикла.

Comment: Очень интересный вопрос, к которому я возвращаюсь время от времени и на который я тоже сам себе так и не могу ответить -- **как правильно измерять время выполнения?**. Вот в этом вопросе код, который делает g++ -O3 для `max1` и `max2` **совершенно одинаков**. А замеры показывают, что  быстрее то одна, то другая (я запускал сотни раз, менял местами блоки с вызовом функций, менял srand() (на константу) и естественно, размер вектора). В среднем, пожалуй, они в самом деле работают **одинаково**. Вот только, как измерять, при иногда (при малых размерах вектора) в разы различающемся clock???

Comment: И что наиболее угнетает, замена `clock()` на такой вот `static inline unsigned long long tick() {
  unsigned long long d;
  __asm__ __volatile__ ("rdtsc" : "=A" (d) );
  return d;
}` tick принципиально ничего не меняет...

Answer (score 4):

Разницы в производительности вышеприведённых функций нет и быть её не может(*). Они могут быть преобразованы в абсолютно идентичный ассемблерный код, что и делает, к примеру, gcc. clang и MSVC генерируют различные инструкции условного перемещения, но их отличие лишь в инструкции сравнения(меньше и больше-равно), что в цифровой логике реализуется одинаково, поэтому разницы никакой не будет.

---

(*) Разница в производительности может быть только в следующих случаях:

- Неправильные измерения
- Ошибка компилятора

Comment: Добавлю конкретный факт. При трансляции g++ -O3 ...  в `Linux x86_64` код **обеих функций одинаков** и состоит из 4-х команд: ` cmpl %esi, %edi;
 movl %esi, %eax;
 cmovge %edi, %eax;
 ret` (я добавил `;` как разделитель)